# Make consistent uuid like hash from file md5 and file name

Tags: python, md5, uuid

I have filecontent and name from post http request and I want to make  name like `8fa14cdd754f91cc6554c9e71929cce7` from filename and file md5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with next code

```
content_hash_md5 = md5()  # noqa: S303
content_hash_md5.update(file_bytes)
content_hash_md5.update(file_name.encode())
base, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)

new_name = content_hash_md5.hexdigest() + ext

with open(new_name, "wb") as fd:
     fd.write(file_bytes)
```